# Tabindex not working for materialDesign:TimePicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabindex, material-design-in-xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Returned}" Style="{StaticResource SectionHeader}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Date}" Style="{StaticResource ContentHeader}" />
    <DatePicker TabIndex="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="200" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Time}" Style="{StaticResource ContentHeader}" />
    <materialDesign:TimePicker TabIndex="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

So the TabIndex works properly for everything except TimePicker. It will just skip to the next TabIndex. I'd like it to tab to the TimePicker in the proper order.

Comment: Hi...James here from MDIX...I have tested this small snippet and it seems OK for me.  If you can post an little repo which illustrates the issue on GitHub I will try and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is because I've tried various ways and it just doesn't follow the tab order I set. The only time it gets selected is if I keep "tabbing" through the controls it eventually gets selected.

I tried setting a TabIndex of both "0" and "1" and I tried setting TabStop to both "True" and "False" but nothing seems to work apart from continuous tabbing and hoping it gets selected.

I even tried setting it in the code behind to just to make sure.

As far as I can gather, it could be that, because it is a part of the Material Design XAML Toolkit, it doesn't support direct TabIndex like native controls.